# Why a JVM requires much more memory than specified heap size to start

Tags: memory, memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory

I have a web application running on IBM wlp web server on a 64bit linux box running java 11. The Xmx=8G specified in jvm.options.  There is a limit of total memory usage for my linux process (by my user id).  When this memory limit is set to less than 20GB, this web server won't start, throwing an OutOfMemoryError. At this point, it's just application start, the java application is not actually doing much such as loading data. For example, if we set the memory limit to 20GB, the web server will start fine, then ps command shows the RSS is only about 470MB indicating it actually only used 470MB if I understand this correctly.  However, the VSZ is 20GB.  If we set the memory limit to less than 20GB, it won't start and throws the OOM error.
Can someone shed some lights on this behavior? Why the JVM requires so much memory to start? More importantly, can the VSZ memory still be used by other programs?  I mean, if my user id is limited to 20GB, but this wlp JVM already "claimed" 20GB as indicated by its VSZ, will I still be able to run other programs not hitting memory issues?

We tried to changed Xmx to 4G, but the behavior is the same. The memory limit must be >2.5 times of max heap size in order for the JVM to start.

Comment: The heap memory is where the Java objects are stored. Then, there is stack memory, program code, I/O buffers, etc. Though, in your case, it’s not even clear whether all the occupied memory is actually used by the JVM. The application could also start new background processes, for example. Factor 2.5 or 12 GB, for off-heap memory is a bit unusual.